# Chart.js chart.update() is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

For my project, I am using vue3 and quasar.

I am building a dashboard, and users can select from a date range, and this date range will subsequently update the charts based on the data in that date range.

In the template/html

```
        <!-- Bar Chart -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 q-my-sm q-gutter-md">
          <canvas id="barChart" ref="barChart" style="height: 350px"></canvas>
        </div>
```

In the script and setup of the vue file

```
const barChart = ref(null); // Ref for barChart canvas element

const barCtx = barChart.value.getContext("2d");

        barChart.value = new Chart(barCtx, {
          type: "bar",
          data: barChartData,
          options: {
            indexAxis: "x",
            scales: {
              y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
              },
            },
          },
        });


      for (const category in salesByCategory) {
        barChartData.labels.push(category);
        barChartData.datasets[0].data.push(salesByCategory[category]);
      }

barChart.value.update();
```

However, from the above snippet, i am getting barChart.value.update() is not a function

From the above, barChart is a ref thus i call it using barChart.value, but barChart.value.update() returns error in console that it is not a function

For context, i am using vue3's composition api.

In the defineComponent setup

```
const barChart = ref(null); // Ref for barChart canvas element
```

In a method createCharts

```
const barCtx = barChart.value.getContext("2d");

        barChart.value  = new Chart ...
```

In a method called "updateInvoicesMetrics"

```
      for (const category in salesByCategory) { ...
      }

barChart.value.update();
```

In vue3's onMounted lifecycle

```
updateInvoicesMetrics(); 
await nextTick(); 
createCharts();
```

In vue3's watchEffect

```
  if ((fromDate.value || toDate.value) && store_invoices.value && barChart.value) {
    updateInvoicesMetrics();
  }
```

Comment: You're mixing up `new Chart` and <canvas> refs

Comment: Please also provide more context for the code.  Is it all running on component creation like the code block implies?  Are you actually creating and immediately updating the chart at the same time (and why)?  or is some or all of this code running in a function that is called some time after creation/mount?  The timing of things like the canvas element mounting and the `new Chart` instantiation matters here.

Comment: Updated in the question with more context

Comment: 1. As mentioned by @EstusFlask, assigning the chart instance (the result of `new Chart(...)`) to `barChart.value` is dubious; assignments to refs `value` are transformed by applying a `reactive` proxy; chart.js instances are not designed for that, and it is completely unnecessary. In your code, you may use a local variable like `const chart = new Chart(...);` and then, later, `chart.update()`.

Comment: 2. As mentioned by  @yoduh the chart usage is dubious: you create the chart with empty data and immediately update it? If there's nothing else there you haven't posted, you should move the `for` that updates data before `new Chart(...)` and remove the `update` call; this way you don't even have to assign the result of `new Chart(...)` to any variable.